# WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "rtspclientsink"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gstreamer, rtsp

I have a gstreamer command that requires "rtspclientsink" and the error I get is:

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "rtspclientsink"

I tried to reinstall gstreamer using the following command:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-libav
>   gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
>   gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
>   gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
>   libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0
>   libgstreamer1.0-0

but I still have this error.

Please help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This particular plugin is not part of the basic three plugin packages.

`sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-rtsp`